# Type bound procedure overloading in Fortran 2003

Tags: oop, fortran, gfortran, fortran2003

I've been programming in Java for a few years; however, I'm now taking a course which uses Fortran as example code (77 standard).  Although I've always viewed Fortran as an ancient language, I decided to try out the latest implementation of the 2003 standard using the gfortran compiler to see its merits for myself.  So far, I've been surprised with the modern features, but I have run into one issue which is demonstrated by the example below.

```
    module mod1
      type type1
        real :: x
        real :: y
        contains
        procedure :: compute
      end type type1
      contains
      subroutine compute(this)
        class(type1) :: this
        this%y = this%x*2 - 1
        write (*,*) this%x,this%y
      end subroutine
    end module mod1

    module mod2
      type type2
        real :: x
        real :: y
        contains
        procedure :: compute
      end type type2 
      contains
      subroutine compute(this)
        class(type2) :: this
        this%y = this%x - 5
        write (*,*) this%x,this%y
      end subroutine
    end module mod2

    program test
      use mod1
      use mod2
      implicit none
      type(type1) myType1
      type(type2) myType2
      myType1%x = 4
      myType2%x = 5
      call myType1%compute
      call myType2%compute
    end program test
```

This produces the compile error:  "Type mismatch in argument 'this' at (1); passed TYPE(type2) to CLASS(type1)" in reference to the `call myType2%compute` statement.

My issue is that of scope.  It seems that, through the `class(<class_name>) :: this` statement, the compiler should be able to bind the subroutine to a specific derived type or its descendants.  From here, it doesn't seem conceptually difficult for the compiler to search for a variable definition starting locally in the subroutine then proceeding up the ancestry tree of the specific instance of `this`.  This would eliminate all the explicit `this%` statements which tend to make my type-bound procedures difficult to read after several statements.  For example,

```
    this%tempNew(xI) = this%lamda*this%temp(xI-1)+(1-2*this%lamda)*this%temp(xI)+this%lamda*this%temp(xI+1)
```

seems to be much less read/writeable than

```
    tempNew(xI) = lamda*temp(xI-1)+(1-2*lamda)*temp(xI)+lamda*temp(xI+1)
```

In the latter case, it is fairly obvious through the `class(<class_name>) :: this` statement, where each variable should be bound.

The other consequence is that it appears that two separate derived types cannot have bound subroutines of the same name (as shown by the error message).  I've seen two common ways around this.  First is to explicitly call each subroutine something like `compute_type1` and `compute_type2`.  When accessing these subroutines, this looks very ugly and redundant in code.  For example `call myType1%compute_type1`.  The second option, (see for example [Overloaded fortran interface with different ranks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434293/overloaded-fortran-interface-with-different-ranks), [Type-bound function overloading in Fortran 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671723/type-bound-function-overloading-in-fortran-2003)) which seems better, is to differentiate the binding name and the procedure name.  For example, the type definition would include `procedure :: compute type => compute_type1`.  This resolves the issue when accessing the subroutine, but I can see issues when developing large projects with many derived types which implement the same binding name.  I'd rather not have to keep track of which subroutine names I have and haven't used in any given project.  This would tend to keep names quite long and less readable in the end.

So my question has 3 components:

- Are there cleaner alternatives to the explicit typing of `this%<var_name>` for class members in type-bound procedures?
- Is there any way to have the compiler recognize that a procedure should be bound based on the `class(<class_name>) :: this` statement?  The current methods of overloading subroutine/function names seem to be an artifact of the 90/95 standard which did not allow these to be bound to types.
- If not, is there some performance gain associated with this implementation?  Both of these issues seem like they could be addressed at compile time, which I would gladly sacrifice for the improved power of expression.

Comment: Your code looks like it should do what you want.  Which gfortran version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version contained in gcc version 4.6.3 for Linux.  The error message can be reproduced if the above code is contained in a single file test.f03 and compiled with `gfortran test.03`

Comment: Remember to specify the standard while compiling your code using the flag -std=f2003 in gfortran, otherwise the compiler will may try to use free form fortran or a different standard. Using the file extension as .f03 will not guarantee that the standard followed by the compiler will be in fact the 2003.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment, but it appears that you're being forced to speculate because of a compiler failing.  I've compiled the code with gfortran 4.8.3 without error, and with the expected result.  Also, it seems to me that what you want to happen should happen.

> The other consequence is that it appears that two separate derived types cannot have bound subroutines of the same name (as shown by the error message).

While both subroutines are called `compute` they are in separate modules and this is allowed, although your `use` statements make a `call compute(...)` (which you aren't doing) ambiguous.  If the type definitions were in the same module then you would have to resort to the `procedure :: compute => compute_typex` trick, but `call mytype1%compute` would still be acceptable.

I would recommend that if you're exposing the `compute` subroutines through the type-binding then you have them as `private` in the module, or at the very least, don't explicitly `use` them.  [That is, have `use mod1, only : type1`.]

As for whether you're stuck with `type%...` in the subroutines, then yes, I think you are.  That said, under Fortran 2008 there is the `associate` construct

```
subroutine compute(this)
  class(type1), intent(inout) :: this
  associate (x => this%x, y => this%y)
    ...
  end associate
end subroutine
```

but that doesn't gain much in this case.  And there are other terrible tricks which I won't detail.

Comment: Incidentally, compiling with version 4.8 also allowed me to drop all the `this%` qualifiers for class members in type-bound procedures without errors.

Comment: Your incidental observation is because your code lacks `implicit none`, not because you are getting the behaviour you want.